# How to bind knockout to the audio play button

Tags: audio, knockout.js

I'm trying to track when a user presses the play button on an audio element on a page using knockout.  Each page has lots of audio elements and I want to log when a user plays one and save it to the server.  My issue is, I can bind an click event to the entire audio element but I'm not sure how to bind it to just the play button.  I tried using the html5 events directly but had trouble with calling the knockout code.

```
<audio 
    controls="controls" preload="none" 
    data-bind="click: $root.audioClicked" 
    type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who's looking at this.  I realised that I needed to use the event binding:

```
<audio 
  controls="controls" preload="none" 
  data-bind="attr: { src: $data.Url }, event: { play: $root.audioClicked }" 
  type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```